# How can I back-up my Home without including previous back-ups?

Tags: backup

I'm trying to create a backup of my home directory, but I want to exclude any previous backups that have been made already.

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean exclude previous backups? Are the backups in your /home and you don't want to back them up? Or do you want to start fresh and delete the previous backups. Please clarify and let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good idea, Because files change, they work all together, creating backup of single files seperately is not good.